# Getting elements from a file that belong to another file

Tags: python, search

First of all, I'm a beginner at Python and the program I wrote may not be the best but it's what I know for now. Also, I know the title might be confusing but I'm gonna explain it clearly.

I have a list of 237 genes of my interest (in a text file, each one in a line) and a text file with more than a million lines and two "columns" splitted by tab, where each line is a pair of genes that interacts between each other. My goal is to get only interactions between my 237 genes of interest.

```
$head exp_genes.txt
gene
gene10120
gene10247
gene1032
gene10377
gene10467
gene10529
gene10533
gene10593
gene10632
```

```
$head int_genes.txt
gene20201       gene171
gene20201       gene699
gene20201       gene746
gene20201       gene803
gene20201       gene841
gene20201       gene940
gene20201       gene957
gene20201       gene1303
gene20201       gene1982
gene20201       gene2162
```

So the logic I followed was looking at the first column and when I found a gene that belongs into my list, I would look at the second column to check if it belonged into it as well. If yes, I'd append this line (vector in the program) into the resulting table (matrix).

```py
def salva(arquivo):
  resultado = "pcw_interactions.txt" 
  def compile_row_string(a_row):
    return str(a_row).strip(']').strip('[').replace(' ', '\t')
  with open(resultado, 'w') as f:
    for row in arquivo:
      f.write(compile_row_string(row)+'\n')
    return(True)

def searchseg(primcol,pcwgenes):
  pcwint=[] #new matrix to save the final result
  for i in range(len(primcol)-1): #sweeping all interactions
    for j in range(1,len(pcwgenes)-1): #sweeping all genes of interest
      segint = primcol[i][1] #getting the second gene of the ith line
      pcwgene = pcwgenes[j] #getting the jth gene of interest
      if segint == pcwgene: #if they match
        pcwint.append(primcol[i]) #save the whole line of interection at the resulting matrix
  salva(pcwint) #call the saving function
  return(True)

def search(pcwgenes, allint):
  primcol = [] #new matrix to save the result
  for i in range(0,len(allint)-1): #sweeping all interactions
    for j in range(1,len(pcwgenes)-1): #sweeping all genes of interest (starting at 1 because the file has a header)
      primint = allint[i][0] #getting the first gene of the ith line
      pcwgene = pcwgenes[j] #getting the jth gene of interest
      if primint == pcwgene: #if they match
        primcol.append(allint[i]) #save the whole line of interection at the resulting matrix
  #when it's finished, I call the next function to look at the second column 
  searchseg(primcol,pcwgenes)
  return(True)  

def abre(nome_arquivo):
  arquivo = open(nome_arquivo) #open the file
  conteudo = arquivo.read() #read the file
  arquivo.close() #close the file
  linhas = conteudo.split('\n') #split by new line 
  colunas = []
  for i in range (len(linhas)): #getting each line
    tabs = linhas[i].split('\t') #split by tab
    colunas.append(tabs) #matrix of vector, each line is a vector with two elements
  return(colunas) 

def abreexp(nome_arquivo): 
  arquivo = open(nome_arquivo) #open the file
  conteudo = arquivo.read() #read the file
  arquivo.close() #close the file
  linhas = conteudo.split('\n') #split by new line, each line will be a element of a vector
  return(linhas)

def main():
  pcwgenes = "exp_genes.txt" #name of the file (list of genes 237x1) 
  pcwgenes = abreexp(pcwgenes) #open the file
  allint = "int_genes.txt" #interactions file 1034253x2
  allint = abre(allint) #open the file
  search(pcwgenes,allint)

main()
```

The output I'm getting has two problems:

```
$ head pcw_interactions.txt
'gene171',      'gene221'
'gene171',      'gene221'
'gene171',      'gene699'
'gene171',      'gene699'
'gene171',      'gene746'
'gene171',      'gene746'
'gene171',      'gene803'
'gene171',      'gene803'
'gene171',      'gene841'
'gene171',      'gene841'
```

1. All lines are duplicated

   So I ran `uniq` command in the bash and got a 7759x2 file
2. It seems it's not efficiently filtering the second column.

   I ran `uniq | wc -l` for each column, the first one has 219 different         genes which makes sense (because it's less then those 237 from my interest list) but the second one has 7749 different genes, thus a lot out of my list of interest.

I've spent all day rewriting, changing little details and re-running this code but couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Maybe someone can see my mistakes or can suggest me better logics or workflows, all remarks all welcome.

Comment: Just a note for you: in your lines `for i in range(len(primcol)-1): #sweeping all interactions` and `for i in range(0,len(allint)-1): #sweeping all interactions`, you should get rid of the `-1` at the end of each; the end of `range()` is exclusive. So if you do a `range` based on the `len` of an object, you don't need to subtract 1 (unless the last line of the file is different)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate your situation.

If `exp_genes.txt` contains:

```
gene
gene10120
gene10247
gene1032
gene10377
gene10467
gene10529
gene10533
gene10593
gene10632
gene20201
gene957
```

And `int_genes.txt` contains:

```
gene20201       gene171
gene20201       gene699
gene20201       gene746
gene20201       gene803
gene20201       gene841
gene20201       gene940
gene20201       gene957
gene20201       gene1303
gene20201       gene1982
gene20201       gene2162
```

This script:

```
genes_of_interest = set()

with open('exp_genes.txt', 'r') as f_in:
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            genes_of_interest.add(line)

with open('int_genes.txt', 'r') as f_in, \
    open('file.out', 'w') as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            g1, g2 = map(str.strip, line.split())
            if g1 in genes_of_interest and g2 in genes_of_interest:
                f_out.write('{}\t{}'.format(g1, g2))
```

produces `file.out` which contains:

```
gene20201   gene957
```

---

Note: As first thing I load the content of `exp_genes.txt` to a `set()`. Then read `int_genes.txt` line by line and test if both columns are in set. If yes, I write a line to output file.

Comment: The output was also duplicated, I've checked both input files and confirmed they're not duplicated so I can't understand why this is happening, but nothing that `uniq` doesn't solve. I've also added a `\n` to the output format parameter. Apart these, it worked perfectly. Thank you.